# Show that $f$ is homotopic to $g$.

Tags: homotopy-theory

> Let $X$ be any topological space. If $f,g:X\to S^n$ (n-sphere) are continuous, such that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are never antipodal, show that $f$ is homotopic to $g$.

I have no idea about this, please guve me some direction. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are never antipodal, then the line through $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ never passes through the origin.

Comment: I voted to close as "I have no idea" is not sufficient to provide context. Where did you get the question from? Were there similar questions you've seen? What did you try? Is there part of the question you are uncertain about? At the moment, your post is little more than a question taken from a book or homework assignment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing that two maps are homotopic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882214/showing-that-two-maps-are-homotopic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea is the the line joining $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ never containts the origin and hence can be projected onto the $S^n$. To be more concrete: Define 
$$ h(t,x) := (1-t)f(x) + tg(x) \in \mathbf R^{n+1} $$
and 
$$ H(t,x) := \frac{h(t,x)}{|h(t,x)|} $$
Then $H$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $F : X\times I \to S^n$ as $F(x,t)= \frac{tf(x)+ (1-t)g(x)}{\left \| tf(x)+ (1-t)g(x)  \right \|}$..

$F$ is well defined and gives you the required homotopy.