# A map without fixed points homotopic to $-x$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Let $ f: S^2 \to S^2 $ be a map without fixed points, then it's 
>   homotopic to $ g(x) = -x $. (Hint: look at a great circle that contains $ x $ and $ f(x)$).

I don't understand the hint. What I tried to do is to do someting like Borsuk-Ulam and take $ g(x) = \frac{f(x) - x}{||f(x)-x||} $, and I don't know how to continue. The only insight I found is that $ f(x) $ isn't nullhomotopic, but that's not seems useful.

So how can I prove that statement?

Comment: big circle? great circle, surely?

Comment: Maybe "great circle" is a better translation. I changed it. Thanks.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/882227/191404).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look in Elon Lages Lima's "Fundamental groups and Covering Spaces". There, he proves the following theorem (at early pages):

If $h: X\to \mathbb{S} ^n$ and $j: X \to \mathbb{S} ^n$ are continuous maps such that $h(x) \neq -j(x) $ for all $x\in X $, then $h \simeq j $.

Clearly, your question is a particular case of this result.

The homotopy $h \simeq j $ is constructed as in Lord Shark the Unknown's answer. Sometimes, it is useful to keep in mind this (general) homotopy/result.

Comment: The result and the book seems interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$H:(x,t)\mapsto (1-t)f(x)+tg(x)$$
is a homotopy between $f$ and $g$, but within $\Bbb R^3$ alas!
But the no-fixed point condition means that $H$ avoids the origin.
So
$$(x,t)\mapsto\frac1{|H(x,t)|}H(x,t)$$
is a homotopy inside $S^2$.